# Use of "off/off of" in speech

Tags: prepositions, expression-choice

Why do Americans say *off of* when they tell someone to *get off* them?

Comment: How do you say it? Some Americans say *Get off me*, some say *get off of me* (this would be particularly appropriate in written English), some say *get (the @#$%) off*. You might be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic English questions.

Comment: I know it sounds a bit smart-ass, but the only answer is 'because they are Americans'.

Comment: Why do you take things *out **of*** boxes, and not just *out* boxes? Taking something *off **of*** a shelf isn't any more illogical than taking something *out **of*** a box.

Comment: @PeterShor How would _Taking something off a shelf_ differ in meaning?  Would you say or write, _'Get the cat off of the table.'_? If such use is now official American grammar then so be it.

Comment: @Joe: Most Americans don't say *off of*, they say *off*. And there really isn't much difference in meaning. If there is any difference, it's that *off of* is the opposite of *onto*, and *off* is the opposite of *on*. But you can find *off of* used in most situations you find *off*.